# Append GIFs vertically in Java

Tags: java, file, animated-gif

I am trying to connect multiple animated gifs vertically. The thing is that I download the gifs from a page and write it to the same file on the fly. So I do not want to create multiple files but rather use DataInputStreams to append to one FileOutputStream.
My example creates a gif but it only shows the first gif from the list that is parsed.

What I want is that, the gif is append below the first gif, however for that I need to set an offeset in `fo.write(b, Offset, 1)` right? I do not know how to determine the offset. In addition if I would just use 0 as offset it should append the gifs to few them one by one, but this is also not working.

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

```
FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream("S:\\folder\\" + nameofthefile +".gif", true);   

    for(String urltoGif : urlstoContent) {
        byte[] b = new byte[1];
        URL urlGif = new URL(urltoGif);
        URLConnection urlConnection = urlGif.openConnection();
        urlConnection.connect();
        DataInputStream di = new DataInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
        while (-1 != di.read(b, 0, 1))
        fo.write(b, 0, 1);
        di.close();

    }    
    fo.close();
```

I can move away from the current solution if there is a better option that works efficient.

Help is greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: basically, you want to make one gif, containing all the gifs you selected?

Comment: The offset in [`write`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/io/FileOutputStream.html) is `the start offset in the data`, not some vertical offset.

Comment: @Stultuske yes exactly. If possible vertically but if not possible also just one after the other

Comment: @Mark ok yes. So I would need to use something else for vertial positioning?